# How to make a trigger only for one of objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a car in my game with 4 wheels(Unity3D):

[image]

Also i have a trigger of EndLevel:

[image: image2]

But after when im going throght the trigger its trying to work 4th times
How can i change it?

I tried to add my "Player(car)" inside EndGame object but its didnt fix my problem.

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class EndTrigger : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameManager gameManager;
       void OnTriggerEnter()
        {
            gameManager.CompleteLevel();

        }
    }
```

Comment: `OnTriggerEnter` takes a `Collider other` parameter. The code you have shown should never be called at all. If you are calling it yourself from somewhere, either make a discriminant there or pass the `other` along to this method.

Answer (score 2):

First of all note that [`OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) requires a parameter of type `Collider` otherwise it wouldn't get called at all.

## Flag

The simplest solution might be adding a `bool` flag as already mentioned by [Eric Warburton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683458/7111561).

## Layers

I would prefer to rather tackle the origin of the issue and suggest using different [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and then configure the [Layer-based collision detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) via the <kbd>Edit</kbd>→<kbd>ProjectSettings</kbd>→<kbd>Physics</kbd>→ `Layer Collision Matrix`.

1. Create a Layer e.g. `END` and assign it to your goal collider object. Make this object **not** `Is Trigger` and rather attach your script checking for `OnTriggerEnter` here.
2. Create a Layer e.g. `Player` create a new dedicated invisible object with a collider and **enable** `Is Trigger` here. This object has the only purpose of colliding with the goal collider nothing else. Assign the `Player` layer here.
3. Configure the collision matrix thus that `END` only collides with `Player` and nothing else. And `Player` only collides with `END` and nothing else - or maybe later another effect layer like e.g. `PowerUps` ;)

   [image]

You can create up to 24 custom layers and make use of the already existing ones so this should hold up a while

## Tags

Another alternative to the Layers is using [Tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual//Tags.html)

As previously I would make the `END` object **not** a trigger but rather use one on the Player.

Then you can simply compare the tag using [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html)

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;

    gameManager.CompleteLevel();
}
```

in very very complex games this might be sometimes better since you can create a lot more Tags than Layers.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few things that I can think of trying.

You can make sure that only one of your colliders is a trigger. There should be a bool check in the properties to uncheck for your wheels.

You can also do something like creating a counter or a bool that prevents the OnTriggerEnter() from firing multiple times if you only want it to fire once. You can reset it at the start of levels if needs be.

Something like

```
void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    if (!gameManager.IsLevelComplete)
        gameManager.CompleteLevel();
}
```

Inside the gameManager script

```
public bool IsLevelComplete { get; set; }

public void CompleteLevel()
{
    IsLevelComplete = true;
    //Do stuff
}
```